# Entity Framework Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my web.config, I have a connection string set which is different in my web.release.config where it is changed to use our production database using an `xdt:transform`. The problem is, I have only been running `add-migration` and `update-database` on the database contained within web.config. Is there some way I can run `update-database` when I publish using the release configuration?

To get around this in the short term, I change the connection string contained within web.config to the one contained in web.release.config and then run `update-database` prior to publishing, but this defeats the purpose of using an `xdt:transform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the VS Publish Web tool, you can check "Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start)" in `Settings`.

If you're deploying to Azure, they can also run migrations on their side, I believe (I remember reading about "new" Azure-specific things regarding this just a couple of months ago, definitely less than a year).

Otherwise, you can always pass arguments to `Update-Database` to target another database (`ConnectionStringName`, `ConnectionString`, `ConnectionProviderName`), you shouldn't have to fiddle with the `Web.config` file.

Comment: I can't use the "Execute Code First Migrations" option as I am using the File System option, not web deploy. But using the arguments whilst typing out `Update-Database` worked, thanks!